# jQuery Validation equalTo not working with Grails

Tags: jquery, grails, jquery-validate

I'm using [jQuery Validate plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) in my Grails application , 
Here is the code from the GSP for the validation:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.save').attr('disabled', true);
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element,e) { 

        return value.indexOf(" ") < 0 && value != ""; 
          }, "${message(code:'sherif.jqueryValidation.nospaces')}");


    $('#myForm').validate({

        errorElement: "label",
        errorClass:'error',
        success: function() {
         $('.save').attr('disabled', false);
         },
        rules :
            {
            username:{required : true,noSpace:true},
            password :{required : true,noSpace:true},
            confirmPassword:{required : true,noSpace:true,equalTo:"#password"},
            contactNumber: { required : true, number:true},
            email:{required:true , email:true}
            }
    ,
        messages : {
            username:{required :"${message(code:'sherif.jqueryValidation.required')}"},
            password : {required :"${message(code:'sherif.jqueryValidation.required')}"},
            email:{required :"${message(code:'sherif.jqueryValidation.required')}" , email:"${message(code:'sherif.jqueryValidation.invalidemail')}"},
            confirmPassword: {required :"${message(code:'sherif.jqueryValidation.required')}" , equalTo:"${message(code:'sherif.jqueryValidation.passwordmatch')}"},
            contactNumber: { required : "${message(code:'sherif.jqueryValidation.required')}", number:"${message(code:'sherif.jqueryValidation.numberonly')}"}
    }

    });
});
</script>
```

All the validations are working fine except `equalTo` validation, although the two password fields have the same value I get a `password doesn't match` error.

Here are the Password fields :

```
 <div class="row form-group">

    <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: usersInstance, field: 'password', 'error')} required">
    <div class="col-sm-2 "><label for="password">
        <g:message code="users.password.label" default="Password" />
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> <g:passwordField style = "width:40%;"  class="form-control input" name="password" required="" value="${usersInstance?.password}"/>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row form-group">
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: usersInstance, field: 'confirmPassword', 'error')} required">
    <div class="col-sm-3 "><label for="confirmPassword">
        <g:message code="users.confirmPassword.label" default="confirm Password" />
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    </div>
<div class="col-sm-9">  <g:passwordField style = "width:40%;"  class="form-control input" name="confirmPassword" required="" value="${usersInstance?.confirmPassword}"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there anything I missed that may cause this error?

Comment: It would help to see the actual RENDERED HTML, then we could verify that the `name="password"` field contains the `id="password"` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...although the two password fields have the same value I get a `"password doesn't match"` error.

You will see this condition if there is no element matching `#password`.

```
equalTo: "#password"
```

Your `#password` selector is looking for an element that contains `id="password"`.  If you cannot add an `id` attribute to this element, you can try the following, which will match by `name`...

```
equalTo: "[name='password']"
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/68a9fkgt/](http://jsfiddle.net/68a9fkgt/)**